# VBA Vlookup condition (if then) source data and vlookup range are on different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need your help with conditional Vlookup. I found a code that works fine if there is vlookup value in the source data but it fails once there is a missing value. Also I need to add a condition ('If the value is found by Lookup, then return "Old" (from 2nd column in vlookup table)
'If the value is NOT found, then return "New" (just text which is not coming from vlookup table). Could you help me?
Thank you,'Russ

```
Sub Vlookup_Condition()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

With ActiveSheet.Cells
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row)

    For i = 2 To rng.Rows.count
        'If the value is found by Lookup, then return "Old" (from 2nd column in vlookup table)
        'If the value is NOT found, then return "New" (just text which is not coming from vlookup
        'table)

        rng.Cells(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Cells(i, 1), Sheets("Lookuptable").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
    Next
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: I think you can accomplish this in a much simpler way.  Just set all sells in column B to Vlookup then just loop over column B with an if statement.  Something like If rng.Cells(i,2) <> "Old" Then rng.Cells(i, 2) = "New"

Comment: Thank you for a prompt reply. I tried to insert If rng.Cells(i,2) <> "Old" Then rng.Cells(i, 2) = "New" after rng.Cells(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Cells(i, 1), Sheets("Lookuptable").Range("A:B"), 2, False) AND before Next. It gives me a Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Vlkookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class. Any thoughts? Thank you!!!

Comment: I am still working on this puzzzle. Do you have any ideas? Thank you

Comment: hey man just got in ill check it out right now and get you some good code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your puzzle. I found a solution like this Russ

**UPDATED & TESTED**

```
Sub Vlookup_Condition() 
Dim rng As Range 
Dim i As Long 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

Worksheets("DataFile").Activate 

Range("R2").Activate 

With Worksheets("DataFile").Cells 
Set rng = .Range("O1:O" & .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row) 

For i = 2 To rng.Rows.count 

rng.Cells(i, 4) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 15), Sheets("Lookuptable").Range("A:B"), 2, False) 
If IsError(rng.Cells(i, 4)) Then
   If rng.Cells(i, 4) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then ' Given if condition to change it from "#NA" to "New"
     rng.Cells(i, 4) = "New"
   End If
End If
Next 
End With 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Jagadish, for prompt reply and great help!!! I have received a run-time error 13 Type mismatch message. What is wrong? Have a nice day!!!

Comment: Type Miss Match Error is Because `#N/A Error` Where all errors in VB are not Variants, So they need special Handling for that. I have Updated the code.Try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Vlookup_Condition()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws as Worksheet 
Dim i As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
i =2 
With ws.Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count)
    .Formula = "=VLookup(" & ws.Cells(2,1).Address & ",Lookuptable!$A:$B,2,false)"
End With 

Do while ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    if ws.Cells(i,2) <> "OLD" Then ws.Cells(i,2) = "New"
    i = i +1
Loop
```

Hope this helps there is a more concise way to do this but this way might be easier to build off of.

Ok after further review TRY THIS! lol

```
With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

        For i = 2 to rng.Rows.Count
            rng.Cells(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Cells(i,1), Sheets("Lookuptable").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I really hope this works for ya mate if not ill probably not do any actual work AT work tomorrow until i figure out how i totally punted this help lol

Comment: Thank you!!! Anyway there is a syntax error in line: .Formula = "=VLookup(ws.Cells(2,1),Sheets("Lookuptable")!$A:$B,2,false)". I am not sure why...

Comment: make the vlookup formula in the formula bar and then just copy and paste it in between the " ".  Hopefully that helps if not we might have to go back to the application.worksheetfunction method.

Comment: No, it didn't help. Also I have seen on the http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/276496-help-writing-vlookup-into-visual-basic-applications-code-2.html that single quotes were used for Sheet name rather than "". It is still work in progress. Can we try application.worksheetfunction method? Thank you,Russ

Comment: we must be tripping ourselves up over something small lol. sec ill adjust code

Comment: FYI this is going to be slow to execute, unless there is good reason to fill a formula in to 1,000,000+ rows of data (assuming Excel 2007+), you need to limit the range more reasonably.

Comment: damn i knew it was something I missed from trying to do it off the top of my head.  and I hope if he has 1,000,000+ rows that your not holding that data in an excel workbook lol

Comment: I appreciate your great help!!! Yes, I have Excel 2010 (1,000,000 line limit is OK). The first code freezes everything. I didn't have a chance to wait until it was completed. The second code stops at the first value NOT included in the vlookuptable giving a run-time error 1004: Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class. I still need to incorporate a condition for values not listed in the vlookuptable and assign a value of "New" to all of them. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!!!